# Why isnt function executed?

Tags: c#, function

I am working on creating an app just like the Output Terminal (Unix) or the Command Line Prompt (Windows). I have created a dictionary that has some keywords for a function. But when I call those keywords, nothing is done. My program is called Command Line Control (or CLC). And I use the .NET Core which is for all running software(Linux, macOS, and Windows).

I do not know what to try exactly. A function is a function. It must be executed when I call it.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace CLC
{
    class Program
    {    
        static DirectoryInfo maindirectory;
        static Dictionary<string, string> keyaction;
        static string value;

        static void WritePathOfWorkingDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
        {
            if (directory != null)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}:", directory.FullName);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        static void ProcessAnswer(string[] array)
        {
            string action = array.GetValue(0).ToString();
            value = array.GetValue(1).ToString();
            string c = keyaction[action];

            Console.Write(c);
        }

        static string ListFiles()
        {
            foreach(var file in maindirectory.GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
            }

            return "ok";
        }

        static string ListDirectories()
        {
            foreach(var directory in maindirectory.GetDirectories())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(directory);
            }

            return "ok";
        }

        static void MainProgramm()
        {
            WritePathOfWorkingDirectory(maindirectory);

            string data = Console.ReadLine();
            var arry = data.Split(' ');

            ProcessAnswer(arry);

            Thread repeat = new Thread(MainProgramm);
            repeat.Start();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            maindirectory = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Users");

            keyaction = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            keyaction.Add("lf", ListFiles());
            keyaction.Add("ld", ListDirectories());

            Console.Clear();

            maindirectory = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Users");

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainProgramm));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is to do what the key says: for example if I type `ld` (list directories) the list directory function should be executed. But I don't get anything! The program just repeats itself.

Comment: You're populating `keyaction` with the results of `ListFiles()` rather than a method reference

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you include the parentheses after a Method name, you invoke the method. So rather than passing the function as the Dictionary value, you're passing the result of calling that function. You need to get a reference to the function to be called then invoke it.

Your Main method should look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        maindirectory = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Users");

        keyaction = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>(); // changed this to an Func instead of a string

        keyaction.Add("lf", ListFiles); // notice I removed the parentheses here

        keyaction.Add("ld", ListDirectories); // and here

        Console.Clear();

        maindirectory = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Users");

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainProgramm));

        thread.Start();
    }
```

and keyaction should be declared like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, Func<string>> keyaction; // a Func<string> is a function that returns a string and takes no arguments
```

Then, in your ProcessAnswer method you need to call the function via the reference you have to it in the Dictionary:

```
 static void ProcessAnswer(string[] array)
    {
        string action = array.GetValue(0).ToString();

        value = array.GetValue(1).ToString();

        string c = keyaction[action](); // calling the referenced funtion

        Console.Write(c);

    }
```

This should give you the expected result.

In the current state, your program's methods only get called once and then you clear the Console before you can see the output, so it probably looks like your program just says "ok" whenever you enter a command.

Comment: It still doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're storing a `string` value in the dictionary rather than the function itself, so when you add the functions, you're adding their immediate return value (before you ever prompt the user for input).

Instead, the dictionary value should be a `Func<string>`, which you can then `.Invoke` on demand.

Additionally, it seemed that you weren't validating the user entry. We can use `TryGetValue` for the user's entry to ensure that they entered a valid command (if it exists in the dictionary). If it doesn't, we can tell them their input was invalid.

Also, when accessing array values, you should first ensure that the index you're accessing is valid (if the user only enters one command, like `"lf"`with no value, then you can't access array index `[1]` because it doesn't exist.

Also, it seems like even when the user does input a path, you store it in `value`, but never use it. So I modified the `ListFiles` and `ListDirectories` methods to treat the value as a path, and if it exists, list the files or directories from the path specified.

Try out this code with the changes:

```
public class Program
{
    private static DirectoryInfo _maindirectory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users");

    private static Dictionary<string, Func<string>> _keyaction =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>
        {
            {"lf", ListFiles},
            {"ld", ListDirectories},
            {"cd", ChangeDirectory},
            {"exit", Exit}
        };

    private static string _value;

    private static void DisplayPrompt(FileSystemInfo directory)
    {
        Console.Write($"{directory?.FullName ?? "[cmd]"}: ");
    }

    private static void ProcessAnswer(IReadOnlyList<string> array)
    {
        var action = array.Count > 0 ? array[0] : string.Empty;
        _value = array.Count > 1 ? array[1] : null;
        Func<string> method;
        _keyaction.TryGetValue(action, out method);

        if (method == null)
        {
            WriteError($"Unknown command: {action}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_keyaction[action].Invoke());
        }
    }

    private static string ListFiles()
    {
        var dir = Directory.Exists(_value) ? new DirectoryInfo(_value) : _maindirectory;

        foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
        }

        return "ok";
    }

    private static string ListDirectories()
    {
        var dir = Directory.Exists(_value) ? new DirectoryInfo(_value) : _maindirectory;

        foreach (var directory in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(directory);
        }

        return "ok";
    }

    private static string ChangeDirectory()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(_value))
        {
            _maindirectory = new DirectoryInfo(_value);
        }
        else if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_maindirectory.FullName, _value)))
        {
            _maindirectory = new DirectoryInfo(
                Path.Combine(_maindirectory.FullName, _value));
        }
        else
        {
            WriteError("Directory not found.");
        }

        return "ok";
    }

    private static void WriteError(string message)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    private static string Exit()
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
        return "ok";
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            DisplayPrompt(_maindirectory);
            ProcessAnswer(Console.ReadLine()?.Split(' '));
        }
    }
}
```